# Executing JMETER Junit Sampler (Selenium Webdriver) using MAven

Tags: jmeter

I have created a simple JMETER Load test which runs perfectly fine from JMETER. I have created the Load test case by:

- Writing a simple JUNIT test in eclipse
- Exporting the JUNIT test as Jar
- Creating a load test using JUNIT test case.

The above works fine within JMETER. However, I am unable to run the same using MAVEN ( JMETER MAVEN Plugin) i.e. test does not run. I can see a message

```
[info] Executing test: JUnitRequest.jmx
[info] Completed Test: JUnitRequest.jmx
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 10.033s
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Jun 07 20:12:40 BST 2017
[INFO] Final Memory: 16M/309M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.lazerycode.jmeter:jmeter-maven-plugin:1.9.1:jmeter (jmeter-tests) on project restapitest: C:\2017\JMETER\RestApiTest\target\jmeter\results\20170607-JUnitRequest.jtl (The system cannot find the file specified) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
```

and then a error message:

Please find below my POM.XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.jmeter.restapi</groupId>
    <artifactId>restapitest</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.lazerycode.jmeter</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmeter-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.9.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>jmeter-tests</id>
                        <phase>verify</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jmeter</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <jmeterExtensions>
                        <artifact>kg.apc:jmeter-plugins:pom:1.3.1</artifact>
                    </jmeterExtensions>
                    <junitLibraries>
                        <artifact>com.lazerycode.junit:junit-test:1.0.0</artifact>
                    </junitLibraries>
                </configuration>

                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                        <version>5.1.17</version>
                        <type>jar</type>
                        <scope>compile</scope>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going forward could you please include the error as well as we are most interested in it rather than in your configuration.

With regards to your question itself, I fail to see any sign of plugging your jar or dependency libraries.

You need to include:

1. Your JUnit jar itself
2. Any dependencies

into the *pom.xml* file. The process is described in details at [Adding additional libraries to the classpath](https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin/wiki/Adding-additional-libraries-to-the-classpath) page of the [JMeter Maven Plugin](https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin) wiki.

My expectation is that your pom.xml file should look somehow like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>jmeter-selenium-junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>jmeter-selenium-junit-test</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>your-junit-jar</id>
            <name>your junit repo</name>
            <url>file:/path/to/your-junit-jar.jar</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.lazerycode.jmeter</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmeter-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>jmeter-tests</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jmeter</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <jmeterExtensions>
                        <artifact>org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:2.52.0</artifact>
                        <artifact>org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-firefox-driver:2.52.0</artifact>
                    </jmeterExtensions>
                    <junitLibraries>
                        <artifact>com.yourcompany.yourgroup:your-artifact:1.0-SNAPSHOT</artifact>
                    </junitLibraries>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

See [Five Ways To Launch a JMeter Test without Using the JMeter GUI](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/5-ways-launch-jmeter-test-without-using-jmeter-gui) article for more information on different approaches to running a JMeter test including Maven plugin

Comment: Thanks a lot Dmitri T. I also tried maven antrun plugin and even that seems to work fine a s well.